# Do you 'tap the jar lid' or 'knock the jar lid'?

Tags: phrase-request

Sometimes, the screwed jar lid is so tight that you cannot open it. One method to make it easy to open is to strike the lid to allow some air entering in or to break the bond solidified.

For the action of beating the jar lid, which expression is correct?

> Tap the jar lid

or

> Knock the jar lid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably a dozen expressions. English is not lacking in variants.

"Tap" and "nudge" imply a gentle application of force.

"Knock" implies a moderate application of force.

"Slam," "whack," and "wallop" imply an extreme application of force.

I am confident that I have missed verbs with different shades of meaning.

The idea that there is always a unique word in English to describe something misses the nuances and power of English.